# Installing xmllint

Tags: xml, dtd, xmllint

I needed help installing xmllint from this website: http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/

In particular, I am not sure which file I am supposed to download - when I click the link for precompiled Windows binaries I am brought to a list of several files and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because link mentioned in the question describes how the dependancies work and an answer would simply be reproducing that. 

Comment: Re edited question: Follow the *other* link to the Windows binaries page: http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

Comment: Hmm...I have downloaded and unzipped the relevant files. But when I try running xmllint.exe it says that I don't have iconv.dll which I do have (and unzipped). Could you advise further?

Comment: More basically how could I edit XML data with DTDs?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had the same problem and it took me two hours to make it work.

1. Download iconv, libxml2, libxmlsec, and zlib from [ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/][1]
2. Extract the zip file then copy all the files in the bin folder of each download.
3. Paste the files in a folder (mine = `XML`)
4. Add the `C:\folderName` (mine = `C:\XML`) in the path system variable.
   (I'm using Windows 8, for Windows 7 users [here's a link](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)):

   - <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (run window)
   - Type control panel then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Type path in search box.
   - Under System, click "Edit the system environment variables".
   - Under the Advanced tab, click "Environment variables".
   - In the System variables look for Path → Edit → add `;C:\folderName`,
   - or **just type `path` in search box located in your Windows 8 charms**.
5. Make it work (I only type xmllint and I had no idea why I cant see the xmllint         window. This is a note for beginners)

   - copy a xml file into the xmllint directory
   - type `xmllint --valid --noout fileName.xml`.

     If you get this message:

     > warning : failed to load external entity "fileName.xml"

     then that's likely a bug so download **an older version** of libxml2 from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/ or **assign another folder** to your XML files and run xmllint from there.

     In the command window :

     - `cd C:\Users\user name\Documents\XML files`.
     - Once you're inside it, type the xmllint commands e.g. `xmllint --valid --noout fileName.xml`).

Reference:

- Installation: http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2011/10/08/3-steps-to-download-xmllint/
- https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/docbooksys/segmentedhtml/ch03s03.html
- Bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=863166

Comment: hi how to make it work for bulk files, when I am trying to replace html content in `<div class="someattr attr2"> and <\div>``--output oldfileName+New.Html`

Comment: Thank you very much!  Still works in 2022 for the WIN32 files.  I did not try to get the 64-bit files to work.  I am using to validate XML with XSD schema using `xmllint --schema my_schema.xsd my_file.xml --noout`

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I have implemented the above steps as a PowerShell script here: https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/f021e09f8c2d492e19959a9978b42544

Answer (score 37):

For users of [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), installing xmllint is rather simple:

```
choco install xsltproc
```

This package contains the `xmllint`, `iconv`, `xmlcatalog`, and `xsltproc` commands, and any dependencies are installed automatically.

Comment: Genious. Side note: `xmllint` did not exactly work as supposed until I started to use it inside the (Git) Bash.

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, the Chocolatey xsltproc package [**installs version 2.9.3**](https://github.com/geraldcombs/chocolatey-packages/blob/5f01bd63ba3c174a1f4013efec55af92f0141107/xsltproc/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1#L69) of libxml2, [**released in 2015**](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/). While non-Windows users can install from the official website [**version 2.12.5 released in 2024**](https://download.gnome.org/sources/libxml2/). Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

On Debian/Ubuntu-derived distributions, `xmllint` is part of the libxml2-utils package.

To install:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-utils
```

On RedHat-derived Linux distros, `xmllint` comes in the same package as the library itself, so it's very likely  you already have it.

Comment: This was a helpful answer to me, but the original question pertains to Windows. Even so, I've submitted an edit to note that this is Debian/Ubuntu-specific. On RedHat/CentOS, the `xmllint` binary is in the same package as the library (libxml2), so you probably already have it.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that xmlsoft.org does not have much information about how to install xmllint in Windows.

Perhaps (as already suggested by Quentin in a comment) the information at http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The link from C.M. Sperberg-McQueen is a good starting point.  You need to 
1) download the libxml2 package, and
2) place the bin folder that comes with this in a directory contained in your PATH environmental variable.

If you don't know how to figure out which directories are in your PATH environmental variable follow this: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm.

Answer (score 1):

at least on `centOS`:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) 
Release:    8.2.2004
Codename:   Core
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

it's as easy as:

`sudo yum install xmlstarlet` so that now `xmllint` is installed as:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20907
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Comment: Those are two different packages. The `xmllint` binary comes from the libxml2 package on CentOS, not [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). Try `rpm -ql xmlstarlet | grep xmllint` then `rpm -ql libxml2 | grep xmllint` (assuming both packages are installed).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows (I'm using 10 Pro, but this could work on most versions I suppose) I work with [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) which provides an ubuntu terminal emulation, and installing xmllint is a one liner:

```
apt install libxml2
```