# XML indentation characters (xmllint)

Tags: xml, linter

I recently installed xmllint in windows using [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618276/1053415). However when I run xmllint against any xml file it adds double quotes at the beginning of the line.
Example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library path="lib/libplugin_triangle">
<class type="triangle::cPlugingTriangle" base_class_type="regular_polygon::cRegularPolygon">
 <description>This is a triangle plugin.</description>
</class>
</library>
```

becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library path="lib/libplugin_triangle">
"  " <class type="triangle::cPlugingTriangle" base_class_type="regular_polygon::cRegularPolygon">
"  " "  " <description>This is a triangle plugin.</description>
"  " </class>
</library>
```

I have played with several definitions of XMLLINT_INDET with the windows environmental variables tool. But nothing happens.

Do these double quotes are legal in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, these quotes are not XML standard**.
The problem was my linter manager (ALE) in my editor (vim). It sets up the XMLLINT_INDENT variable to textually " ". That is a bug in ALE. Then xmllint place these characters. I proposed a fix for that error in [this pull request](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/pull/3469),